# What is a "tote"?

Tags: meaning

From http://www.sterilite.com/home.html?section=1, there are different kinds of storage boxes. One kind is called "tote". I wonder what it means and how it is different from others?

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you?

Comment: This is a specialist's term and is not well explained by general references.

Comment: A verb, which I can not relate to my question.

Comment: There are different types, shapes, and sizes of storage boxes available to accommodate nearly all of your needs. Why are you asking just for that? Do you have specific needs?

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: What kind of special needs is for tote?

Comment: @ΜετάEd "Tote bag" is an entry in all the three dictionaries that I have checked.

Comment: Tote bag != tote box.

Comment: Tote for a box isn't in any dictionary I can find and it seems to be a purely American usage - so not obviously reference

Comment: @mgb OED: **“tote** *n⁴.* :   **c.** ***tote bag***, a large hand-bag or shoulder-bag; ***tote box***, a portable box for small items.”  Voting to close as General Reference.

Comment: In English we can noun verbs and adjectivize nouns. If you know the meaning of **tote** the verb, you can garner the meaning of **tote** the adjective. In this case, if you click on the totes in your link you can *see* how they are different from the others. They have handles and can be easily toted: "The 30 Gallon Tote features in molded handles for easy transporting".

Comment: @ΜετάEd What specialty is that?

Comment: Tim, this question might have survived had you simply included the meanings from the dictionaries you found, and then explained why none of them seemed to adequately describe those mysterious _totes_ at the hardware store. By omitting that key information, you created the appearance that you hadn't done any preliminary research, which in turn prompted a lot of skepticism. I dispense this advice often: if you don't want your question being closed as "general reference," think carefully about the first impression your question is bound to create; if necessary, elaborate on _why_ you're puzzled.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I had in mind the shipping tote, which was not relevant to the question. I checked in through a tiny mobile device and got the wrong impression.

Answer (score 2):

Tote for *carry* as in cargo is from the 1600s - eg "tote that bale"

More recently it's used for an open bag, at least in American English.
I think Tote for a large box with handles may be specific to this company, just to try and create a name for a specific box in their range. I've only heard it in American English where this brand is sold.

Comment: I don't know, I think that "tote box" is a simple extension of "tote bag".

Comment: It may be an Americanism, but Sterilite isn't the only company using the term _tote_; [other brands](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=rubbermaid+totes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=rubbermaid+totes&hl=en&rls=en&prmd=imvns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=r_knUJ7LD6TtygHDjIHABQ&ved=0CLQBELMY&fp=1&biw=1239&bih=871&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&cad=b&sei=x_knUKGUOKm1ygGPiYHACA) use that word, too, as do [Lowe's](http://www.lowes.com/Search=totes?storeId=10151&N=0&langId=-1&catalogId=10051&rpp=16), Home Depot, and [Ace](http://www.acehardware.com/search/index.jsp?kwCatId=&kw=totes&origkw=totes&sr=1).

Answer (score 1):

The first photo below shows an example of tote boxes.  They typically have handles, making them easier to *tote* around.  The other photo shows a family of totes.

[image] 
[image]